# How can I cancel a Rails AJAX request completely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

We have an autocompleter which makes an AJAX request after each letter is typed in a text box (after a delay).  Even with the delay, it turns out to be a lot of requests, most of which are ignored.

I know we can abort the AJAX request, but how can we make sure Rails aborts its processing (including any current DB query)?  Can closing the connection raise some kind of exception?

Comment: Since auto-complete responses should be fast, it might actually take longer to determine a request should be canceled instead of throwing away the result.

Comment: If we could make these queries that fast, we wouldn't have this problem.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it depends on your web server of choice.  Rack doesn't have explicit support for detecting it.

[On unicorn](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/mongrel-unicorn/2011-August/001099.html), it looks like there may be some trickery you can perform by tweaking enumerable returned back to rack.  (If it stops calling `each` before the request finishes, then the client aborted the request)